# Correct way to use args parser subparser set defaults with imported functions?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface

I currently have a bunch of stand alone functions that I am trying to implement into a CLI program using argsparse.

The standard way to incorporate functions as command line args seems to be as follows (from the blogs I read):

```
from consolidate_all_files import consolidate_all_files #my function
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="functions for file processing")
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    consolidate_parser = subparsers.add_parser("consolidate_files")
    consolidate_parser.add_argument('src')
    consolidate_parser.add_argument('dest')
    consolidate_parser.set_defaults(func=consolidate_all_files)
```

I don't quite understand how `consolidate_all_files` will be called with `set_defaults`. 
My `consolidate_all_files` function looks something like this:

```
import os
import shutil

def consolidate_all_files(MAIN,DIRS)
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(DIRS):
        '''Basically we move all files from subfolders into one folder '''
            print('root', root)
            print('subdirs', subdirs)
            print('files', files)
            for file in files:
                    path = os.path.join(root, file)
                    try:
                        shutil.move(path, MAIN)
                    except shutil.Error as e:
                        continue
```

Most examples I have seen on the web, seem to have their function parameters/arguments revolve around parser args. So would I need to go through each function and change its parameters to something like:

```
def consolidate_all_files(args)
        for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(args.src):
            '''Basically we move all files from subfolders into one folder '''
                print('root', root)
                print('subdirs', subdirs)
                print('files', files)
                for file in files:
                        path = os.path.join(root, file)
                        try:
                            shutil.move(path, dest)
                        except shutil.Error as e:
                            continue
```

or is there a way to get my original functions to become compatible with subparser's set defaults.

Thank you.

Comment: definitely missing in your main:                                                                                        args = arg_parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)